# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In console, I can see that `releaseLink` has the correct value (a link) that is being grabbed. But on the next line when I try to create a click event for it, I get this error in console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

here is the jQuery:

```
var releaseLink = $( "#release-link")[0];
var previousLink = $( "#prev-link" )[0];

  releaseLink.on('click', function(){
    console.log('hello. you clicked the release notes link');
  });
```

here is the html that is associated with it.

```
<div id="release-notes">
    <h3><a id="release-link" href="#">Release Notes</a></h3>
    <div id="release-notes"></div>
</div>

<div id="previous-versions">
     <h3><a id="prev-link" href="#">Previous Versions</a></h3>
     <div id="version-notes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `[0]` in `$( "#release-link")[0]` and `$( "#prev-link" )[0]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Using the array access `[0]` on a jquery result set will return the native `DOMElement`, and a native `DOMElement` does not have the jQuery function `.on`

Comment: @j08691, your comment is true, but useless without explanation, because the reason why it doesn't make sense is not that obvious, especially to a beginner.

Comment: cool. so when i grab it without the [0], jQuery is returning the element in side of an array, it looks like this: ` [ <a id=​"release-link" href=​"#">​Release Notes​</a> ​] `  how do I grab it so it is not in an array?

Comment: @GolezTrol - It's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @j08691 And so I didn't downvote. ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol - What were you going to downvote, my comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But using `[0]` you have stripped the jQuery object into a DOM Element. `.on` is a jQuery method, and is not defined on DOM objects.

There's no need to use `[0]` anyways, since you're selecting by ID. Unless you're duplicating element IDs, which is illegal HTML, it's safe to assume your jQuery selector will only return one object.

Comment: that  makes sense, however i have a simple click event happening on it, a console log. I have taken the [0] off, and when the element is clicked, i am not getting the console log - do you see a reason why?

Comment: @HolyMoly with the array notation removed it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wx8bwu7k/

Comment: indeed it does, not sure why it is not working locally for me - have the exact same thing. i will mark the answer as correct and figure it out...thanks all!